# Error when fetching all members in the guild

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I get this error when fetching the members

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')
    at C:\Users\darke\Documents\Honorus bot\2\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberManager.js:504:24
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at GuildMemberManager._fetchMany (C:\Users\darke\Documents\Honorus bot\2\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberManager.js:501:12)
    at GuildMemberManager.fetch (C:\Users\darke\Documents\Honorus bot\2\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberManager.js:208:31)
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\darke\Documents\Honorus bot\2\src\commands\Community\interactionGiver.js:19:49)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Object.execute (C:\Users\darke\Documents\Honorus bot\2\src\events\interactionCreate.js:15:13)
```

It is random every time i restart my bot most of the time I get the error but sometimes it works until I restart it again

here is my code

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders')
const reactionGiverSchema = require('../../reactionGiverSchema')

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName('reactiongiver')
    .setDescription('Used to give a role when reacting to a message')
    .addStringOption(role => role.setName('message_id').setDescription('L\'ID du message pour donner la réaction').setRequired(true))
    .addChannelOption(role => role.setName('channel').setDescription('Le channel dans lequel se trouve le message').setRequired(true))  
    .addRoleOption(role => role.setName('rôle').setDescription('Le rôle a donner après la réaction').setRequired(true))    
    .addBooleanOption(role => role.setName('reset').setDescription('Faut-il enlever le rôle au personnes qu\'il l\'ont déjà').setRequired(true)),
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        const channel_ID = interaction.options.get("channel").channel.id
        const role_ID = interaction.options.get("rôle").role.id
        const message_ID = interaction.options.get("message_id").value

        if (interaction.options.get("reset").value == true){
            const guild = await interaction.guild
            const members = await guild.members.fetch()
    
            members.forEach(element => {
                const roles = element._roles
                if (roles.includes(role_ID))
            });
        }

        

        await reactionGiverSchema.create({ message_ID : message_ID, channel_ID : channel_ID, role_ID : role_ID})
        await interaction.reply({ content: "Creation effectuer", ephemeral: true})
    }
}
```

I haven't found anybody with the same error except someone who had this error because his bot wasn't ready but I'm sure that mine is when I use the command

i tried to fetch all members in my ready event but i get the same error

after reinstalling the nodes modules it worked 2 times before i got the same error

Comment: Are you sure the error you are showing is coming from this code?

The error mentions a send statement while your code has none.

Comment: @Dan, that's coming from the [GuildMemberManager](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/14.7.1/packages/discord.js/src/managers/GuildMemberManager.js#L504), meaning `this.guild.shard` is `undefined`. That usually happens when the bot is not ready.